# Get Path data or Compare Elements of Path<List<X>> for Predicate

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am trying to construct a predicate that will succeed if any of the elements of a `List`, referenced by a `Path<List<X>>`, satisfy equality for one of the members of `X`.

However, I cannot determine whether the data can be directly accessed. None of the methods I saw allow access to that data, and I cannot use the existing expression methods to do the above.

Here is code of what I'd like to be able to do, to do this comparison based on the `y` attribute of the `X` class:

```
List<X> xPredicates = new ArrayList<X>();
for(X x : this.getX()) {
    for(X x2: m.get("xList").getActualList()) {
        xPredicates.add(cb.like(x2.y, x.y));
    }
}

Predicate actualPredicate = cb.or(xPredicates);
```

Comment: It isn't clear - it looks like you are dealing with a list of 'x' - did you want something that matches against all Xs, or an 'or' predicate list where the xList just has to match against one. ie xList.contains (x1) && xList.contains(x2)... vs xList.contains (x1) || xList.contains(x2)...
What about the code you wrote isn't working the way you want?

Comment: I want it to match against a list containing an X having a Y attribute, and yes, afterwards I would ```cb.or``` the list to get the actual predicate.

This is criteria builder, so ```m.get``` does not return a list, it returns a ```Path<List<X>>```. The above code does not work because you can't read a member of a ```Path```, nor can I index or iterate over it. I wrote it to try to illustrate what I would like the code to be doing.

What I'm looking for is an alternative using this Path that will match on any X having a member with a particular value.

Comment: I edited the (non-working, part psuedo-)code to hopefully be more clear about what I am trying to do.

Comment: Looks like you are also accessing 'y' within the X, not just X directly for comparison. JPQL "select distinct e from YourEntity e join e.xList xList where xList.y in :parameterListXOfYValues". IN uses equality, so if you need 'like' comparison logic, you'll have to pass each X.y value separately. Using join to the collection allows you to use elements of it, so if 'm' is the root, it is just Join<YourEntity, X>  xListPath = m.join("xList");

Comment: I assume the join would need a ```.on(...)``` afterwards? How could I then create a Predicate? Is it possible to pass some part of the join into an Expression?

Comment: Try JPQL I provided, or directly translate it to criteria expressions - join extends expression. Join<YourEntity, X> xListPath = m.join("xList"); Predicate actualPredicate = xListPath.get("y").in(listXOfYValues);